# how to provide environment variables to AWS ECS service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

Trying to create a service in ECS and unbelievably looks like it is not possible to specify any environmental variables...

Is it possible to do that without updating my task definition and recreate the service? Or a task override option?

This looks a bit cumbersome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `environmental variables` are provided through [task definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_environment). Thus you have to update the definition to add/change the variables.

You don't have to re-create the service from scratch. You can **update your service** to use the new version of your task definition. For updating existing service you can use [update-service](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecs/update-service.html) AWS CLI call. The cli also provides `--force-new-deployment` if you want to force the deployment (but changing task should be enough and forcing would not be required).

Comment: > `changing task should be enough`

You mean that if I update (create a new revision) of my task definition should be enough to trigger a new service deployment? Thanks

Comment: @Madeo No problem You still would have to trigger the update,  because updating the task would create a new version of the task. So you have to tell your service to use the new task version in place of the old one.

Comment: I see, it is just strange I cannot inject env variables when I create a service, what could the reason for not allowing this?

Comment: Your task can have multiple containers. So you specify the en-variables at container level.

Answer (score 2):

You can't define environment variables at service creation time as explained by the other answer but you can define tags: thus one workaround is to

1. Create a service with a set of tags and [`propagateTags: SERVICE`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateService.html#ECS-CreateService-request-propagateTags)
2. On container startup read the cluster and task ARNs from the [task metadata endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4-fargate.html)
3. Read service tags with the [`DescribeTasks` API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeTasks.html) (note the `include: ['TAGS']` parameter)
4. Configure the environment using the tag values

Comment: has the [task metadata endpoint] (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4-fargate.html) changed? because I can't see a **task ID**  nor any related field in the endpoint response...

Comment: Right, that should've been task ARN instead of task ID. I fixed the answer, thank you!

Comment: Do you need step 3? Is it not possible to read tags directly from the task metadata endpoint?

Comment: Yes since the [task metadata endpoint response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/task-metadata-endpoint-v4-fargate.html) does not include tags, unfortunately.